# UWP DataGrid disable Keyboard behaviors

Tags: uwp, datagrid

Help me please.
I have DataGrid on page and when I put "Enter" button row is changed on next. I have read in MS site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/keyboard_navigation_selection about DataGrid keyboard navigation and selection modes. 
How can I disenble the "Enter" button navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe the [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netcore-3.1) event of DataGrid, it will occur before the KeyDown event when a key is pressed while focus is on this control. Then judge if this event is triggered by pressing the Enter key. If it is, set the `KeyRoutedEventArgs.Handled` as true to mark the routed event handled.

.xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown" x:Name="dataGrid1" ...>
...
</controls:DataGrid>
```

.cs:

```
private void dataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter) {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: big thank you. I did it but I writed e.Handled = false;